# angular routing dynamic without component

Tags: angular, dynamic, routes

I have a question.

I try to build routes by the angular router. If i use normally it work all fine.
Example:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: "Systems",
        component: AppComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "Identities",
        component: AppComponent,
    },
]
```

What I try to do is, load child routes without create routes.

I'm on Page http://localhost:4200/Systems. And try to fire a link to http://localhost:4200/Systems/sub1. But I don't now the name of, the next page, sub1 on init the app.
So is it possible to set a new router by somthing like `this.router.navigate(['sub1'])....`? Can I create routing for Systems/.... from codeside?

And than on page sub1 I set link to a page = `http://localhost:4200/Systems/sub1/sub2`, and so on.

I want to create dynamic routing without set the routes at Init. I want add routes at the moment I load the next part of App. The url be grow with every link.

I hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to create child routes for `Systems/` path. This child route will take a variable called `:sub`. So that you can route to `Systems/sub1` and `Systems/sub2` etc

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: "Systems",
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
              {path: ':sub', component: AppComponent} 
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "Identities",
        component: AppComponent,
    },
]
```

Comment: Hello,
thank you for the fast answer. I understand what you mean and it works. But my problem is, that I can have a lot of :subs, and I don't know how much.

So I can't create children in children in children for my "/sub1/sub2/sub3..." url.

So it is possible to generate the children dynamic? Or a new routing by loading the new page? So that I can extend the url bei X subs.

Comment: So, do you load different components every time or its just the url that will change? If it is the same component every time, then you can simply add `pathMatch : 'prefix'` to the child route like `{path: ':sub', component: AppComponent, pathMatch : 'prefix}`. That should load the component for any `sub1/sub2` url

Comment: So thanks for your Infos. i tried both and both of them was helpfull.

What I found too:
       `this.router.resetConfig([
            { path: urlName, component: AppComponent }
        ]);
        this.router.navigate([urlName]);`

For example you can use the code in a function to create a new url.